# How to deploy Stale Pod (I mean non operational) through gitlab CI?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I would like to deploy an application and the pod should not go to running status(it should be non-operational). User might trigger this when it really requires using Infrastructure as Code (Terraform). I am aware of using `kubectl scale -- replicas=0` . Any other leads or info will be well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the replica count to **zero** for the **Deployment** or **POD** into your **YAML** file if you are using it.

Or if you are using the **Terraform**

```
resource "kubernetes_deployment" "example" {
  metadata {
    name = "terraform-example"
    labels = {
      test = "MyExampleApp"
    }
  }

  spec {
    replicas = 0

    selector {
      match_labels = {
        test = "MyExampleApp"
      }
    }

    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          test = "MyExampleApp"
        }
      }

      spec {
        container {
          image = "nginx:1.7.8"
          name  = "example"

          resources {
            limits = {
              cpu    = "0.5"
              memory = "512Mi"
            }
            requests = {
              cpu    = "250m"
              memory = "50Mi"
            }
          }

          liveness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/nginx_status"
              port = 80

              http_header {
                name  = "X-Custom-Header"
                value = "Awesome"
              }
            }

            initial_delay_seconds = 3
            period_seconds        = 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no other way around you can use the [client](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) of Kubernetes to do this if don't want to use the Terraform.

If you want to edit the local file using the terraform checkout **local-exec**

> This invokes a process on the machine running Terraform, not on the
> resource.

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  # ...

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${self.private_ip} >> private_ips.txt"
  }
}
```

using **sed** command in **local-exec** or any other command you can update the YAML and apply it.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html

Comment: I would like to thank you Harsh Manvar, I am aware of this method where I can use replicas =0 either in deployment.yaml or in Terraform file. I also did lot of research, there is no other way to deploy.  Also, Imagine I deploy an app with replica=0, how can I scale to 1 from Terraform for an existing deployment. Note: I don't want to use kubectl command and scale it back.

Comment: if you have issue of managing the TF and kubectl, you have to reply TF only for scaling up the of or you set some automation which scale by own using client lib. Or HPA.

Comment: Thanks again, I know about scaling and automation. I think that here you didn't understand my question properly. Let me more clear. I have an existing deployment.yaml(replicas=0). I need to scale this deployment file using IAC(Terraform). I mean I need to edit existing deployment using Terraform. It's just a straight forward.

Comment: chekcout the updated the answer : https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html